# Show DialogFragment on AsyncTask.onPostExecute when activity is in background;

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment

I got a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` when trying to show a dialog after the Activity goes to background, I need to show this message to the user, is there any methods to show the dialog when activity is resumed. My code is something like this:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_progress_message));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // HTTP POST user action
        // App goes to background (user press home button i.e.)
        // Getting message from server
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        DialogAlert dialogAlert = DialogAlert.newInstance(message);
        dialogAlert.setCancelable(false);
        //App crash here
        dialogAlert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);

    }
}
```

I have tried with `AsyncTaskLoader` but the dialog doesn't show up when activity resumes. Any ideas.

Comment: You can use DialogActivity to display the dialog wen Activity goes to background..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code snippets,

Replace

```
dialogAlert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(dialogAlert, "tag")
                           .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```